# load a combo with AJAX in VueJS (onLoad)

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to fill a combo with VueJS.

My HTML:

```
...
<select class="form-control">
    <option v-for="federation in federations" v-bind:value="federation.value">
    @{{ federation.text }}
    </option>
</select>
...
{!! Html::script('js/userForm.js') !!} // <- Laravel style to include js
```

Here is my  Vue file (userForm.js):

```
let Vue = require('vue');


let vm = new Vue({
el: 'body',
data: {
    federations : [],
},
computed: {},

methods: {
    getFederations: function()  {
        var url = '/api/v1/federations';
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            this.federations = data;
        });
    }
    // ,ready() {
    //     this.getFederations();
    // }
},
filters: {}
});
vm.getFederations();
```

Thing is getFederations get executed, with an array of object, so, it is ok, but, still when debugging in the Vue Console, federations value is default [] set in data.

I also tried with ready() method but not working neither...

Anybody kwno why???

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `this` is not what you think. In your case, `this` is the `jqXHR` object of the Ajax call, not the Vue instance.

You should assign `this` to a support variable:

```
 getFederations: function() {
   var url = '/api/v1/federationsofcats';
   var myVm = this;
   $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        myVm.federations = data;
   });
 }
```